# As I'm just a student, I don't have enough money to take a class that (takes / imposes) me high cost. -Can you help me find proper word to use here?

Tags: word-usage

> As I'm just a student, I don't have enough money to take a class that (takes / imposes) me high cost.

I don't know what word I have to use in this context. But I vaguely remember someone using takes in this situation. Can you help me find proper word to use here?

Comment: As I'm just a student, I don't have enough money to take a class, which demands me high cost.

Comment: I think "incur" *may* fit, but I don't think it's at all idiomatic. I would've up-voted answers that suggest a more idiomatic phrase, if your question asked for a rephrase; but you ask for a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no word you can put there that results in a grammatical sentence.  You could say:

> As I'm just a student, I don't have enough money to take a class
>   **that costs me a lot**.
>
> As I'm just a student, I don't have enough money to take an
>   **expensive** class.
>
> As I'm just a student, I don't have enough money to take a class that
>   **has a** high cost.

Comment: In the first sentence, "me" would probably be implied.

Answer (score 2):

A typical idiomatic way to express this (in AmE) is:

- That class is **too expensive**—I **can't afford it**.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers show, there are many ways of expressing the intended sense. But sticking as close as possible to OP's original suggestion...

> *I don't have enough money to take a class that **imposes** a high cost **on me***.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22imposes%20a%20high%20cost%20on%22) are a few hundred written instances where *[something expensive] **imposes a high cost on** [those who pay for it]*, but note that there are even more instances of the plural form [*imposes **high costs** on*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22imposes%20high%20costs%20on%22) (which would be equally acceptable in OP's example, and means the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the word "demand".

As I'm just a student, I don't have enough money to take a class, which **demands** me high cost.

Comment: No. Firstly, you can't use ***demand*** ditransitively like that, and secondly it's not very idiomatic to use ***high cost*** without an article. It would have to be *which demands **a** high cost **of me*** (or somewhat more "poetically", *which demands **of me** a high cost*).